# Why does Lucene's IndexWriter updateDocument method take only one Term in its parameters?

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I have noticed that the [updateDocument method](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#updateDocument%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term,%20java.lang.Iterable%29) takes only one Term in its parameters.
I find it strange because the [deleteDocument](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#deleteDocuments%28org.apache.lucene.index.Term...%29) can take multiple terms or even a query to select the document(s) to be deleted...

Why does updateDocument not let us specify more than one Term ? Is there a technical reason behind it or is it just that it hasn't been implemented yet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I did not write this code nor I know the exact reasons, so I can only guess.

First of all, update in Lucene has always meant combination of delete + insert whereas delete has always been single operation. Yes, update is now atomic but you still need to `.commit()` for changes to take effect.

Secondly, I guess it's hard to design clean API for updating multiple documents. For each document (which itself is a collection of fields) you would have to pass a collection of terms, so for multiple documents you would have to have a collection of collections (or a specially designed command object), yuck. [And when in doubt, leave it out!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw) What's wrong with asking a customer to have a loop? It's not that complex really.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't explain why I am asking this question. I am developing a search module. Its index contains documents of various origins and I would like to be able to update them using an id AND a type (here "id" and "type" are my own notions for my own model of documents). With the updateDocument, I can't do it directly. A delete (using a query containing the id and the type) and then an add could do the trick. But because Lucene doesn't natively do it, I am wondering if I haven't missed something fundamental about the way it works.

Comment: No, you havent. Just do delete + insert, there's nothing wrong about this. As you will have to `.commit()` at the end anyway (plus reopen the index reader), this operation will look like atomic for the end user.